# iPhone:Upload photo to flickr

Tags: iphone, upload, flickr, photo

I am developing a application where i want to load the photo on flickr. i don't want to use the toolkit. I want to use flickr API.I read the API documentation of flickr but there are no API to upload photo on particular account. All API related to Garden not to user account.

i simply want to user will supply username and password , then I pass the username,password and photo content to API (or web service). 
Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Flickr's API documentation for uploading: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html
And a sample request: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.example.html

Comment: hi ole,
I already know the link provided by you. The problem is that how can I get token through iPhone application. I am able to get frob and then build the auth url on the base of parameter (api_key, params, frob, api_sig) but how can i handle the callback delegate for this url(check it -http://www.flickr.com/services/auth/?api_key=c9642d04825d4e2b5be85d66a34989a3&perms=write&frob=72157623531399851-1f3f469ef9b52aaa-74504&api_sig=8f00016d123169c0f6ccc027ca200d63) in iPhone application. since call of this url require first login detail and then authorize. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Rupesh, check out this post by the Flickr devs, explaining in detail the process of authorizing your iPhone app against a users account:

http://code.flickr.com/blog/2009/11/19/building-authorized-flickr-apps-for-the-iphone/

Hope that helps,

Iain