# How to submit photo via http from iphone application

Tags: iphone, http, web-services, photo

Does anyone have any idea how can I save/upload a photo from iphone application via http?

Thanks

Comment: That depends on the service you are uploading to. Where do you want to upload the photo?

Comment: I am using .net webservice. What I would like to do when user select a photo in iphone application and hit submit I want to upload this photo via http to the hard drive where web service is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the SDK available, you'd need to go through the `UIImagePicker` control to select a photo, convert it to `NSData`, apply the appropriate encoding and the perform the HTTP post.

Here's a code snipper showing how to use the UIImagePicker control:

http://www.ikangai.com/blog/development/code-snippet-of-the-week-uiimagepicker

Comment: Also have a read of:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128378/upload-photo-to-arbitrary-ftp-with-iphone-app

and

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482082/iphoneupload-photo-to-flickr